# Exponential distribution solving X^2, lambda value known

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with exponential distribution with parameter    $\lambda=2$. The expectation of the random variable $Y=X^2$ is equal to

**a)** 1/2

**b)** $\sqrt{2}/2$

**c)** 1

**d)** 2

**e)** 4

I've done this.
$$\mathbb{E}(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda} \implies \mathbb{E} = \frac{1}{\lambda}=0.5.$$
Should I now do some kind of integration using $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ or some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If $X$ is a random variable with pdf $f(x)$ then
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x) dx.
$$

Can you apply this to your problem? What is $g(x)$? Can you integrate?

Comment: instead of f(x) do I place 1-e^-lamda*x?

Comment: that's CDF. you need pdf

Comment: I think I got.it, will try to solve now...

Comment: I've found the answer.